# Should methods return nil or empty array if no data was found/calculated?

Tags: c#, java, php, c++, objective-c

This is generic question and it's interesting what approach do you use guys and what are pros and cons? Sometimes methods return lists (for example, `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray` in obj-c) and my current approach is to return nil if there's nothing to return. It makes sense to return nil if it's just object of some native or custom class, however should we return alloc'ed/init'ed empty array if nothing was found?

The question is primarily targeted for `objective-c` but is also related to other languages. `Objective-c` has nice feature to call methods on `nil`, however this is not the case for all other languages. So it's also interesting to hear arguments from other devs (`java`, `c#` and `PHP` devs).

**UPDATE** It's strange why some are voting on closing the question. Design pattern related questions also could be described as personal opinion questions, however architecture & code quality questions are more important thing than just syntax questions.

Comment: Return an empty container if the result set is empty. Throw an exception if the process went wrong at some place. Don't ever return nil / NULL / nullptr, as SEGFAULT is lurking in the shadows, and the extra check in the calling function bloats the source. Anyways, this is a question for personal opinion, so I'm voting to close this as "not a real question".

Comment: Well, this is not really true for PHP. In PHP, it doesn't really matter what you return as long as you're doing it consistently. In PHP, it's a common practice to return either `null` if the method was supposed to optionally retrieve a single entity or an empty array if it's supposed to return multiple entities. (If it is expected, however, to retrieve at least one, you'd throw an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

There is not a single answer I believe.

For myself I decided to return the result of expected type if possible and NULL otherwise.

Say, in my homebrewed DAL the `getAll` method returns an empty array (list) - so it can be passed to PHP's `foreach` operator without raising an error.
On the other hand, the `getRow` method, which is supposed to return an associative array, returns NULL in case of none data found, as empty array would be as equally useless.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a null and an empty container have two different meanings in my opinion. An empty container would mean, `no result matched your query but it was successful`, while a null result would mean `something went wrong`.

In the first case if you have written code somewhere to say:

```
  print "You have found" + GetResults.Size() + " results"
```

You will be able to print that zero results matched the query. While if you decide on using `null`, you will have to add explicit checks.

I have also had some troubles with serializing result to JSON as a response to a web server request, later on I regretted that I chose to return null instead of empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Return nil or whatever is clearly a non-thing. Don't do more work than needs to be done.

Returning an empty array may cause many useless pointers and structures to be allocated, when all you really need is to say, "I have nothing for you."

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa,

If you return a `nil` to some array you need to check afterwards, that you are not trying to access the array Index.

And it is good to return `nil` instead of an array without any object.